# Include a formula in a user defined function

Tags: r

Let's say I want to calculate a specific value per row or group (in this example question this value is a mean) how would I do that?

```
Personal_mean <- function(observations, data, na.rm){
  #Take obs from data
  observations <- eval(substitute(observations), envir=data)
  #add the observations together
  sum_of_obs <- sum(observations, na.rm=na.rm)
  #adjusts for NA in data 
  if (na.rm==TRUE){
    length_of_obs <- length(observations[!is.na(observations)])
  } else{
    length_of_obs <- length(observations)
  }
# applies above calculations per observation of the object
  m<-0
  for(i in 1:length(observations[!is.na(observations)])){
    m[i]<- sum_of_obs[i]/length_of_obs[i]
  }
  return(m)
}
```

I want to test this function with the following example data:

```
testdata <- data.frame(Gr,O1,O2,O3)
Gr <- c("G1","G2","G3","G4","G5")
O1 <- c(5,7,10,3.5,5)
O2 <- c(4,8,20,NA,3)
O3 <- c(6,NA,18,5.5,2)
```

So this should yield the means of 5,7.5,16,4.5 and 3.3
Basically what I want this function to do is calculate the mean per each row or group, be able to deal with NA's in data, be able to take the observations from the provided data. 
Whenever I try this code I get the following result:

```
[1] 7.461538       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
[11]       NA       NA       NA
```

So what am I doing wrong here that it's not working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative albeit not the best. You can refactor as you may find necessary:

```
my_mean<-function(data,func,observations,na.rm=F,exc){
m<-as.data.frame(mget(observations,envir = as.environment(data)))
  if(na.rm==T){

  #m[is.na(m)]<-as.numeric(0)
  res1<-apply(m[complete.cases(m),],1,func)
  m<-m[!complete.cases(m),]
  ms[is.na(ms)]<-0
 res2<-rowSums(ms[,-exc])/2
 return(list(res1=res1,res2=res2))
 #res2  contains mean for rows with NAs
 #exc is the column to exclude ie has non numeric data
  #res1 has mean for all rows with no NAs
  }else{

    apply(m,1,func)
}
}
```

Testing:

```
my_mean(testdata,mean,c("O1","O2","O3"),na.rm = F,1)


 #  $res1
  #      1         3         5 
  #   5.000000 16.000000  3.333333 

   # $res2
   #   2   4 
    # 7.5 4.5
```